# Can someone explain me this statement. "Antisymmetric relation is an equivalence relation".

Tags: relations

"Antisymmetric relation is an equivalence relation"
Whenever I used to prove this statement I come with a counterexample.
Let take A= {1,2,3,4}
If R= {(1,1),(2,3),(3,4)} then R is antisymmetric but not equivalent.
Can someone explain to me how the above statement is true?

Comment: Where is this coming from? The statement is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is not true that every antisymmetric relation is an equivalent relation but we can have antisymmetric relations which are also equivalent relations.

For example $$ R=\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)\} $$is both equivalent and antisymmetric on the set $ A= \{1,2,3\}.$

Comment: Thanks for help. My opinion is also same about this statement.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.